# JS not recognizing a string from a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string, html

I am trying to grab a string I'm reading in from an XML file to a JS function. For some reason the debugger in Chrome says the value in Glist is not a string.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

    <title>GAGEmobile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/MenuStyle.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="generalBody" runat="server" dir="rtl">

   <form runat="server" id="hidden">
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" value='' id="Glist" />
    </form>

    <%
       var reader = new GAGEmobile.Models.ReadXML();
       var data = reader.getDataFromXML("https://gagemobile-
       demo.servicebus.windows.net/gagemobile/gage/15/sample/david/blah");
       this.Glist.Value = data;
    %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            displayGageInfo(String("<%: Glist.Value %>"));
         });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

the string in GList is:

> "Gage number|C-01001|Gage type|Caliper|Gage size|1 |Units of measure|Inches|Gage description|Digi inside w absolute encoder|Storage location|Tool Crib|Current location|Tool Crib|Status|Available|Owner|Company|Group|Calib Group|EmailTo|Bobby Mohr|Last calib date|3/28/2013|Calib due date|9/28/2013|Last RR date|9/5/2012|RR due date|9/5/2013|Last maintenance date|2/27/2013|Maintenance due date|2/27/2015|Manufacturer|Fowler|Model number|FIC-23451|Serial number|18732|Comment|CALIBRATION GROUP EXPLANATION
>    We defined the  Calibration Group  as a set of gages that will be calibrated all at the same time. We set this value using the Group field above. This allows us to easily filter for these gages and gather them for calibration.
>    SCHEDMAINTDUE EXPLANATION
>    We have also used the user defined fields to create a new field called SchedMaintDue. This field allows us to define a Scheduled Maintenance Due Date for easy access to filtering and reference of maintenance cycles on our gages."

While I have the string in the server code everything is fine. It's when I pass to JS something goes wrong and I have no idea why.

I've tried using the escape() and toString() functions in JS.

Edit:
The error occurs at 'displayGageInfo(String("<%: Glist.Value %>"));' as an unrecognized token

The ASP.NET that reads the XML:

```
public string getDataFromXML(string url)
{
   var xml = new XmlDocument();
   xml.Load(url);
   return xml.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Does the string include those double quotes? (begin and end)

Comment: @millimoose `Value` is correct as that expression is evaluated server-side.

Comment: You haven't posted the client-side code where the problem occurs. Or whether the input field has the expected value in the DOM inspector. Also, using inline scriptlets is kind of confusing.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no those are the double quotes that are around '"<%: Glist.Value %>"'

Comment: @AntP Yeah, I just noticed I mis-skimmed the code sample.

Comment: @millimoose It's not even entering the function.

Comment: why is it `displayGageInfo(String("<%: Glist.Value %>"));`
 and not  `displayGageInfo("<%: Glist.Value %>");` or client side only: `displayGageInfo($("#Glist').val());` since you insert the value in above.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I was trying to cast it, but obviously that didn't work.

Comment: @BrianM What function? Are you getting any errors in the developer console? If you are, where are they coming from if your code isn't being called? How does the Javascript code that the server outputs look like? Why even have the hidden field when you're not really using it for anything and are passing the string directly to a functioln? You'll have to be more specific about what you discovered during diagnosis.

Comment: @millimoose the error I get in the JS console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL GageInfoTemplate.aspx:28. I need the hidden field because I process the XML on the server.

Comment: @BrianM 1. Edit it into your question. 2. Point out where in your code samples the error occurs, since line numbers won't match up between your code and SO. (And also SO doesn't show line numbers so you'll save us counting.) 3. If it's a syntax error we'll **absolutely** have to see the code as output by ASP.NET, not just the `.aspx`

Comment: To do it server side it would be `displayGageInfo("<%: Glist.Value.toString(); %>");` or as above that `displayGageInfo("<%: data.toString(); %>");`then?

Comment: Also, remember that `<%: ... %>` encodes strings to be safe in **HTML**. It's not even remotely supposed to escape a string to make it safe inside a Javascript string literal. I'd avoid dynamically generating JS *completely* and transfer data to your scripts through hidden fields (as you're almost doing), or in `data-*` attribuets.

Comment: @BrianM Right click on page in Chrome. Click "View Page Source". Then show us the Javascript code that corresponds to `displayGageInfo(String("<%: Glist.Value %>"));` **in the actual generated HTML**. I need to see the Javascript code that the browser ultimately processes.

Comment: @millimoose what is in the cod in the HTML via the browser is `displayGageInfo("The string I posted");` The string is far too long to get to format correctly, but what I have posted for the string in the OP is literally what shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not allow string literals to contain literal newlines in them. You have to escape the newlines to `\n`. That is what is causing you the syntax error.

You should never try to express dynamically-calculated values as JavaScript literals manually. Instead, use the correct tool for the job, such as [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer). Your ASPX modified to use this looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        displayGageInfo(<%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Glist.Value)%>);
     });

</script>
```

Notice these things I have changed from your code:

- I have switched from `<%:` to `<%=` because JSON is HTML-safe as long as it is not used as part of an attribute value. Also, ASPX by default sends files to the client with `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`, so if the `"` in the JSON had been entity-encoded to `&quot;`, the browser would try to read the `&quot;` verbatim instead of interpreting it as `"`. (When the browser interprets the file as XML, `&quot;` is perfectly acceptable here).
- I have removed the double-quotes you inserted manually. JavaScriptSerializer takes any given object and expresses it as JSON. In this case, your input is a `string`, so JavaScriptSerializer renders the entire JavaScript String literal and not just the insides.
- I removed `String()` which is redundant because a String literal is already a string ;-).

Comment: @BrianM - You have accepted this answer but I hope you are not going down this route. Circumventing the very paradigm of the framework like this and preferring a broken mix of client-side code with server tags is going to lead to a horrendous, buggy, unmaintainable mess of a solution.

Comment: Whether or not it makes sense to pass the data to the client through an `<input type="hidden"/>` (which would work more naturally and be more concise with the help of `<%:`) or as a JavaScript literal is a different issue. I attempt only to show how to properly encode JavaScript literals. Unfortunately, I do not know APSX nor the framework paradigm. I am completely confused as to why there even is `<input type="hidden" runat="server" value='' id="Glist" />` in the first place.

Comment: It's not a separate issue. The quality of an answer is dependent upon it conforming to good practice as defined by the standards of the technology in question. Not simply by the fact that it "works." This is still broken, as the hidden field itself will remain unpopulated when the page is rendered. The use of a hidden field is the right idea as it is a clean and conventional way to hand server side data to client side code. All this solution does is patch up the holes - it doesn't solve the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your string has a newline in it (right after "CALIBRATION GROUP EXPLANATION"). This will be HTML-encoded in your tag; however, in the server-side evaluation of `GList.Value`, it will be converted to a newline, which is not escaped by `HtmlEncode`.

Because of this, you have a newline in your string literal in the resulting JS. This is not valid.

Do away with the server tags and change your Javascript to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        displayGageInfo($('#Glist').val());
    });
</script>
```

This will avoid the nasty business of dynamically generating string literals in code blocks and let your client-side code be concerned with doing your client-side processing.

Additionally, your inline code will execute too late to actually populate the value in your hidden field. I expect that if you examine your rendered markup, the hidden field will still have no value after it has been loaded. This is because server tags are executed **after** the `PreRender` event, which is your last chance to make changes to controls. You need to run this code earlier in the page lifecycle (try `Page_Load`):

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reader = new GAGEmobile.Models.ReadXML();
        var data = reader.getDataFromXML("https://gagemobile-
        demo.servicebus.windows.net/gagemobile/gage/15/sample/david/blah");
        this.Glist.Value = data;
    }
</script>
```

You will also need to switch on `AutoEventWireup` for the page, to ensure that this method is fired on the Page's OnLoad event:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the passes an empty string.

Comment: See my edit. I would recommend going back to basics and learning about creating aspx pages with codebehinds as you are missing some key concepts here.

Comment: So I guess the issue occurs when I try to save the `data` to the hidden field?

Comment: The second issue does, yes. Because your server tags (`<% .. %>`) are executed after the field's contents have already been finalized.

Comment: For more information on ASP.NET page lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx